# Why I get this warning "Missing Push Notification Entitlement"

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm uploading an ipa to apple store but get email warning from apple.

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.

But I don't want and didn't register any remote notification in my code or any call like "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes". How can I remove this warning? Thanks

My app doesn't have push notification capability. 
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing Push Notification Entitlement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, my profile doesn't contain aps-environmen key and I don't enable this service. The waning is saying app is using API, but I'm not

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251123/

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to ***disable/turn off*** the [APNS capability](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html) from your project if it is included already.

Answer (score 0):

How about check your distribution provision?