# Missing Push Notification Entitlement Warning in email

Tags: ios, push-notification, app-store, apple-push-notifications

After uploading the App to AppStore, I am getting the following warning in an email, where as there are no Push Notifications in my App but there are some third party SDKs like Chartboost, Applovin, Revmob, Crashlytics etc. Has someone else also encountered this problem? If so, have you reached to some solution?

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Jigsaw App". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to
>   correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
>   API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
>   app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
>   Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>   If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
>   developer for information on removing the API.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Comment: Just recreate your provisional profile and then upload your app

Comment: Provisioning Profiles are automatically being created from Xcode.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251123

Answer (score 0):

It means your provisioning profile does not support apns. create a provisioning profile with push notifications enabled and upload.

Comment: There are no Push Notifications in my code, then why should I create provisioning profiles with Push Notifications enabled?

Comment: If there are no push notifications in your app, just ignore this message. Everything else is fine.

Comment: I have been ignoring it but was thinking of some better solution

Comment: How is it a better solution? If I have to enable something which is not in my code :S

Comment: Ok. Then remove registration of remote notifications from your app delegate.

Comment: There is no registration for remote notifications in my app delegate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88378/discussion-between-fawad-masud-and-munahil).

Answer (score 0):

Check out for third party frameworks like

- airpush
- urbanship

etc...

These frameworks can register your app even though you don't register it in app delegate

Make sure push notification is disabled in these frameworks