# Taco Cordova with Visual Studio DISABLE PUSH NOTIFICATIONS for Apple Store

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, taco

I have programmed an app and uploaded at the Apple store. I got a warning from apple that "Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app includes an API for Apple's Push Notification service, but the aps-environment entitlement is missing from the app's signature. To resolve this, make sure your App ID is enabled for push notification in the Provisioning Portal. ..". I have no push notifications or plugin in my app.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: It could be a bug of Apple's Checking System. Since it is just a warning it won't prevent you from deploying the app. See [similar case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251123/missing-push-notification-entitlement) .